# Custom data structure via counting words by paragraph in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, data-structures

I have a requirement to accomplish the following:

- For a given word or token, determine how many paragraphs it appears in (called a document frequency)
- Create a data structure (dict, pandas dataframe, etc) that has the word, its collection (overall) frequency, and document frequency

An example dataset looks like this:

```
<P ID=1>
I have always wanted to try like, multiple? Different rasteraunts. Not quite sure which kind, maybe burgers!
</P>

<P ID=2>
Nice! I love burgers. Cheeseburgers, too. Have you ever gone to a diner type restauraunt? I have always wanted to try every diner in the country.
</P>

<P ID=3>
I am not related to the rest of these paragraphs at all.
</P>
```

A "paragraph" is defined by the existence of the `<P ID=x> </P> tags`

What I need is to create a data structure that looks somewhat like this (I imagine it being a `dict`):

```
{'i': X Y, 'have': X Y, etc}
```

or, probably a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
| Word | Content Frequency | Document Frequency |
|   i  |         4         |          3         |
| have |         3         |          2         |
| etc  |         etc       |          etc       |
```

Currently, I am able to find the content frequency without a problem using the below code.

```
import nltk
import string
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
import csv
import numpy
import operator
import re

# Requisite
def get_input(filepath):
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    return content

# 1
def normalize_text(file):
    file = re.sub('<P ID=(\d+)>', '', file)
    file = re.sub('</P>', '', file)
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    all_words = tokenizer.tokenize(file)
    lower_case = []
    for word in all_words:
        curr = word.lower()
        lower_case.append(curr)

    return lower_case

# Requisite for 3
# Answer for 4
def get_collection_frequency(a):
    g = {}
    for i in a:
        if i in g: 
            g[i] +=1
        else: 
            g[i] =1
    return g

myfile = get_input('example.txt')
words = normalize_text(myfile)

## ANSWERS
collection_frequency = get_collection_frequency(words)
print("Collection frequency: ", collection_frequency)
```

which returns:

```
Collection frequency:  {'i': 4, 'have': 3, 'always': 2, 'wanted': 2, 
'to': 4, 'try': 2, 'like': 1, 'multiple': 1, 'different': 1,
'rasteraunts': 1, 'not': 2, 'quite': 1, 'sure': 1, 'which': 1,
'kind': 1, 'maybe': 1, 'burgers': 2, 'nice': 1, 'love': 1,
'cheeseburgers': 1, 'too': 1, 'you': 1, 'ever': 1, 'gone': 1, 'a': 1,
'diner': 2, 'type': 1, 'restauraunt': 1, 'every': 1, 'in': 1, 'the': 2,
'country': 1, 'am': 1, 'related': 1, 'rest': 1, 'of': 1, 'these': 1, 
'paragraphs': 1, 'at': 1, 'all': 1}
```

However, I am currently removing the "headings" of a paragraph in the `normalize_text` function with the lines:

```
file = re.sub('<P ID=(\d+)>', '', file)
file = re.sub('</P>', '', file)
```

because I do not want `P`, `ID`, `1`, `2`, `3` to count in my dictionary since those are just paragraph headings.

How then can I tie the occurrence of a word back to its instance in a paragraph that would yield me the desired results above? I am not sure even the logic of attempting to create such a data structure.

Comment: Your example dataset is representative? There will always be opening and closing `P` tags?

Comment: Yes. It is generated from a report our company runs. I believe there could be the case that nothing is within the tags, but I have never seen that. Regardless, the tags themselves will always exist. I only copied out three examples to be a representative subset, but there are over 20,000 in some files (all with open and close tags) @wwii

Comment: Do you have to use `nltk`?

Comment: No, outside of the two bullets, nothing is "required". I used `nltk` because it was easy for a novice like me. @wwii I can use or not use just about anything I want (assuming we don't have to pay for anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How then can I tie the occurrence of a word back to its instance in a paragraph that would yield me the desired results above?

Split the process into two parts: finding paragraphs and finding words

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
import re, collections

p = r'<P ID=\d+>(.*?)</P>'
paras = RegexpTokenizer(p)
words = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
```

While parsing keep two dictionaries: one for collection frequency and one for document frequency.

```
col_freq = collections.Counter()
doc_freq = collections.Counter()
```

Iterate over paragraphs; get the words in a paragraph; feed the words to the col_freq dict, and feed a set of the words to the doc_freq dict

```
for para in paras.tokenize(text):
    tokens = [word.lower() for word in words.tokenize(para)]
    col_freq.update(tokens)
    doc_freq.update(set(tokens))
```

Combine the two dictionaries.

```
d = {word:(col_freq[word], doc_freq[word]) for word in col_freq}
```

---

There is some inefficiency there - parsing the text twice - but it could be tweaked if it becomes a problem.

[`RegexpTokenizer`](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html) really isn't doing anything more than `re.findall()` in this case but it *hides* some details and makes this less verbose so I used it.

---

Sometimes `re` doesn't do well with ill-formed markup. Parsing the paragraphs could be done with BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
for para in soup.find_all('p'):
    tokens = [word.lower() for word in words.tokenize(para.text)]
    print(tokens)
##    col_freq.update(tokens)
##    doc_freq.update(set(tokens))
```

Comment: Isn't `collections` undefined in this sense?

Comment: ?? yep, I forgot the import statement - editing now - thnx

Comment: I wanted to make sure before I upvote and accept. This is a great idea and is exactly what I was looking for and perfectly satisfies the requirements (also, is quite fast I might add).

Comment: Bonus: `import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=('collection', 'document')).T`

Comment: I have so much to learn. This is incredible. I will ask a question if I need to, but this seems to have everything I could need. I hope this was good question for you

Comment: From the beginning of your question, it appears that you had identified that you had two similar but separate requirements/processes but then you wrote a solution for one of them without making provisions for the other. Maybe if you had spent more time thinking about the similarities and differences you wouldn't have written yourself into a corner. Sometimes it helps to write ideas down on paper and review it before actually writing any code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer

def normalize_text(file):
    file = re.sub('<P ID=(\d+)>', '', file)
    file = re.sub('</P>', '', file)
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    all_words = tokenizer.tokenize(file)
    lower_case = []
    for word in all_words:
        curr = word.lower()
        lower_case.append(curr)

    return lower_case

def find_words(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        file = f.read()
    word_list = normalize_text(file)
    data = file.replace('</P>','').split('<P ID=')
    result = {}
    for word in word_list:
        result[word] = {}
        for p in data:
            if p:
                result[word][f'paragraph_{p[0]}'] = p[2:].count(word)
    print(result)
    return result

find_words('./test.txt')
```

If you want to group by paragraph, then by word occurrences:

```
def find_words(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        file = f.read()
    word_list = normalize_text(file)
    data = file.replace('</P>','').split('<P ID=')
    result = {}
    for p in data:
        if p:
            result[f'paragraph_{p[0]}'] = {}
            for word in word_list:
                result[f'paragraph_{p[0]}'][word] = p[2:].count(word)


    print(result)
    return result
```

It is still a bit difficult to read though.  If pretty printing the object is important to you, you can try using a [pretty printing package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).

To find the number of paragraphs a word occurs in:

```
def find_paragraph_occurrences(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        file = f.read()
    word_list = normalize_text(file)
    data = file.replace('</P>','').lower().split('<P ID=')
    result = {}
    for word in word_list:
        result[word] = 0
        for p in data:
            if word in p:
                result[word] += 1

    print(result)
    return result
```

Comment: this is incredible. I can not wrap my head around how to create such a structure. How can I create something a little different, though. Ideally, I would not want to search for a specific word, but instead, count the frequency of the words that exist (i.e, the results of my `normalize_text` function). I am concerned with finding the # of paragraphs they each appear in, not necessarily which paragraphs they do appear in (since some files have more than 20k paragraphs). I have tried to reflect this need in my question. Please let me know if I am unclear. I am desperate.

Comment: Sorry, I am slow. I replaced the `['Cheeseburgers', 'is']` with my `words` list object and that is working. But, as elegant as the 'word': 'paragraph_x': y_occurrences' format is, it is very hard to read. How can I instead get the total count of paragraphs, ***not*** total count of occurrences group by paragraph?

Comment: you can swap the `for` loops to do this.  One sec I'll add another update.  Also I added an update using your `normalize_text` function

Comment: @JerryM.  if you still don't like the format, and if the paragraph IDs always start with 1, you could give each word an array of occurrences for each paragraph.  For example `{ "i":[6, 1, 2, 0] }`

Comment: Thank you very much Caleb. I hope to accept your answer as answer, and I have saved all variants. Is there noway to simply count the number of paragraphs a word appears in? i.e. `{'i': 3, 'have': 2, etc}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198850/discussion-between-jerry-m-and-caleb-goodman).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def create_dict(text):
" Dictionary contains strings for each paragraph using paragraph ID as key"
  d = defaultdict(lambda: "")
  lines = text.splitlines()
  for line in lines:
    matchObj = re.match( r'<P ID=(\d+)>', line)
    if matchObj:
      dictName = matchObj.group(0)
      continue  #skip line containing paragraph ID
    elif re.match(r'</P>', line):
      continue  #skip line containing paragraph ending token
    d[dictName] += line.lower()
  return d

def document_frequency(d):
" frequency of words in document "
  c = Counter()
  for paragraph in d.values():
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', paragraph)
    c.update(words)
  return c

def paragraph_frequency(d):
"Frequency of words in paragraph "
  c = Counter()
  for sentences in d.values():
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentences)
    set_words = set(words)  # Set causes at most one occurrence 
                            # of word in paragraph
    c.update(set_words)
  return c

text = """<P ID=1>
I have always wanted to try like, multiple? Different rasteraunts. Not quite sure which kind, maybe burgers!
</P>

<P ID=2>
Nice! I love burgers. Cheeseburgers, too. Have you ever gone to a diner type restauraunt? I have always wanted to try every diner in the country.
</P>

<P ID=3>
I am not related to the rest of these paragraphs at all.
</P>"""

d = create_dict(text)
doc_freq = document_frequency(d)    # Number of times in document
para_freq = paragraph_frequency(d)  # Number of times in paragraphs
print("document:", doc_freq)
print("paragraph: ", para_freq)
```

Result

```
document: Counter({'i': 4, 'to': 4, 'have': 3, 'always': 2, 'wanted': 2, 'try': 2, 'not': 2,'burgers': 2, 'diner': 2, 'the': 2, 'like': 1, 'multiple': 1, 'different': 1, 'rasteraunts':1, 'quite': 1, 'sure': 1, 'which': 1, 'kind': 1, 'maybe': 1, 'nice': 1, 'love': 1, 'cheeseburgers': 1, 'too': 1, 'you': 1, 'ever': 1, 'gone': 1, 'a': 1, 'type': 1, 'restauraunt': 1, 'every': 1, 'in': 1, 'country': 1, 'am': 1, 'related': 1, 'rest': 1, 'of': 1, 'these': 1, 'paragraphs': 1, 'at': 1, 'all': 1})
paragraph:  Counter({'to': 3, 'i': 3, 'try': 2, 'have': 2, 'burgers': 2, 'wanted': 2, 'always': 2, 'not': 2, 'the': 2, 'which': 1, 'multiple': 1, 'quite': 1, 'rasteraunts': 1, 'kind': 1, 'like': 1, 'maybe': 1, 'sure': 1, 'different': 1, 'love': 1, 'too': 1, 'in': 1, 'restauraunt': 1, 'every': 1, 'nice': 1, 'cheeseburgers': 1, 'diner': 1, 'ever': 1, 'a': 1, 'type': 1, 'you': 1, 'country': 1, 'gone': 1, 'at': 1, 'related': 1, 'paragraphs': 1, 'rest': 1, 'of': 1,'am': 1, 'these': 1, 'all': 1})
```